# Dropdowns not populating correctly with PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, sql-server, foreach

I am currently populating a table with rows from a database. One of the columns is a dropdown that needs to be populated with multiple values.

Each dropdown is automatically defaulting to Bowling Green even if that row should not be Bowling Green. Most rows are either Southeast or Michigan but regardless of what it should be, it is defaulting to Bowling Green for some reason.

How can I have the dropdowns keep all values as options in the dropdown (bowling green, michigan, southeast), but have the dropdown value default to the value that it is in the database?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT TOP 100 *
        FROM Table_OS_List
        ORDER BY [CURRENT_SKU] ASC";


$drops = "SELECT [Purchasing_Group]
        FROM Table_OS_List
        GROUP BY [Purchasing_Group]";
$drop = $dbh->query($drops);
$allDrops = $drop->fetchAll();
?>

<?php
/* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows) {
?>
<tr class="row">    
    <td class="old_sku" id="old_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['OLD_SKU'])?></td>
    <td class="current_sku" id="current_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['CURRENT_SKU'])?></td>
    <td class="id" id="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?></td>


    <td class="dropdown-select" id="purchgroup">
        <select id="selected_group" class="selected_group" disabled>
            <?php 
            foreach($allDrops as $dropdown) { ?>

              <option class="choice" 
                      value="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>">
                <?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>
              </option>

            <?php } ?>

        </select>
    </td>


    <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?>" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Example of what it looks like now. You can see that it has multiple options which is what I need, but, regardless of it's value in the database, is defaulting to Bowling Green:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to mark the appropriate `<OPTION>` with the `SELECTED` attribute.

Comment: That's because it is the first option in the dropdown. For it to select it based on the value from the database, you need to add the `selected` attribute to the option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `selected` attribute to the correct option.

Something like this:

```
<option class="choice" 
      <?php echo $row['Purchasing_Group'] == $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'] ? "selected" : ""; ?>
      value="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>">
<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>
</option>
```

Where `$row['Purchasing_Group']` is the column in the `Table_OS_List` table.

The important code here is `<?php echo $row['Purchasing_Group'] == $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'] ? "selected" : ""; ?>` - this is known as a [`Ternary`](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators), it could also be written in expanded form like this:

```
<?php
    if($row['Purchasing_Group'] == $dropdown['Purchasing_Group']) {
        echo "selected";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is perfect and is what I needed...thank you. Will accept this as the answer when I am able to

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Glad that I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `selected` attribute with a inline ternary operator just like so;

```
<option class="choice" <?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'] ? ' selected' : null ?>   value="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>">
                <?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>
              </option>
```

and after you fetching all the datas from the DB, always good to check if result or results existing.

Comment: Every row should have an existing result in OP's code, your code will add `selected` to every single option, you have to check if the option it's creating is the same as the row.